# Displaying table data into horizontal alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table of 1 column and say 5 rows.

The (data in the) rows are displayed one bellow another (vertically) in the table by default.

I want to display these data (in the table) in a horizontal alignment using CSS and / or javascript. (table of column 1 and rows 5 must remain the same)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have 1 row and 5 columns? Or instead of a table use divs with float: left?

Comment: Yes, I have reasons not to change the table markup. I just to want to display the same table in a horizontal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your example table right?

http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

And you want them to be horizontally?

http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But if you must use `<tr>`'s and cant change the structure, then using `display: inline-block;` is not the best solution. First of all, you need special fix for ie7, when using inline-block and also it will leave spaces.

http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/4/

```
tr {display: inline-block;}
```

Using `float: left;` is your best bet, as far as browser compatibility goes. Also leaves no spaces, but you must put `<br style="clear: both;" />` after `</table>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/5/

```
tr {float: left;}
```

Comment: I cant change the table markup. There is only one table with 1 column and 5 rows.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle? Or is it basically the first jsfiddle that I created?

Comment: How-to Get from example 1 above to example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/silkster/h8AZJ/3/

Comment: This is not crossbrowser and also will leave caps, you still need to remove all spaces between the `<tr>`'s http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/4/  Now, using float is the best bet: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/h8AZJ/4/  However, if its single column table, why not use `<ul>`-list?

Comment: @Silkster, much respect! For not posting your answer with my original fiddle. But you have a completely different approach then I, so go ahead. Your script is a very valid answer to this question. Though, mine is more simpler ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/YPvxP/

```
#table tr, #table td {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that IE won't particulary like that.

Comment: Simple and useful suggestion, but if it is not working in IE, this can't be put into production. Any javascript trick as IE workaround?

Comment: try `display: inline;` instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: Then padding settings wont work. Also it still leaves spaces. Face it, `float: left;` is the best way. If you want to make the display: inline-block; work in ie7 also, then: tr {zoom: 1; *display: inline; display: inline-block;} this should fix things for ie7 and ie6. Bet you didn't know that..

Comment: @Kalle I honestly don't know what you're talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/YPvxP/7/

Comment: Ok, basically inline works. But your fiddle's css is incorrect. `td, tr {}` should be maybe `tr, td {}`. In that example, you are adding padding to tr aswell -- thats wrong. Also, why do you even need to add display: inline; to td? http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/YPvxP/8/ And as you can see, there are SPACES between the cells.

Comment: Also, as I said before. Ie7 doesn't support this. Not even display: inline;!